# How can I use xcodebuild to target an older version of iOS?

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, xcodebuild

I'm using XCode 15 on macOS Ventura.

Under Xcode -> Settings -> Platforms, I have installed:

- iOS 17
- iOS 15.5 Simulator

But in Terminal, when I do `xcodebuild -showsdks`, I only see:

> iOS Simulator SDKs:   Simulator - iOS 17.0            -sdk
> iphonesimulator17.0

I want to target the iOS 15.5 simulator-- how do I specify that?